# Getting the error NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.cassandra.thrift.TBinaryProtocol when using Apache Cassandra,Kundera,Spring MVC

Tags: spring, maven, spring-mvc, cassandra, kundera

I keep getting the message

```
 java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.cassandra.thrift.TBinaryProtocol: method <init>(Lorg/apache/thrift/transport/TTransport;)V not found
 at com.impetus.client.cassandra.schemamanager.CassandraSchemaManager.initiateClient(CassandraSchemaManager.java:446)
at com.impetus.kundera.configure.schema.api.AbstractSchemaManager.exportSchema(AbstractSchemaManager.java:101)
at com.impetus.client.cassandra.schemamanager.CassandraSchemaManager.exportSchema(CassandraSchemaManager.java:138)
at com.impetus.kundera.configure.SchemaConfiguration.configure(SchemaConfiguration.java:172)
at com.impetus.kundera.configure.ClientMetadataBuilder.buildClientFactoryMetadata(ClientMetadataBuilder.java:45)
at com.impetus.kundera.persistence.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.configureClientFactories(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:352)
at com.impetus.kundera.persistence.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:116)
at com.impetus.kundera.KunderaPersistence.createEntityManagerFactory(KunderaPersistence.java:83)
at com.impetus.kundera.KunderaPersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(KunderaPersistence.java:65)
```

Whenever I try to run my Java Spring MVC 3.2 Project. I am trying to connect to Apache Cassandra 1.2.8 that I have installed on my machine from the Spring WebApp using Kundera. I have included the following dependencies in the pom.xml file of the project:

1. scale7-pelops(1.3-1.1.x)
2. cassandra-all & cassandra-clientutil (1.2.8)
3. kundera-core & kundera-cassandra (2.6)

My Spring Project uses XML-less configuration (Java Config) and JPA apart from kundera's persistence.xml which is under {PROJECT}/src/main/resources/META-INF so as to be at the base of the classpath during deployment. My persistence.xml looks like:

```
    <persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
        version="2.0">
        <persistence-unit name="cassandra_pu">
            <provider>com.impetus.kundera.KunderaPersistence</provider> 
            <class>org.tutiworks.orm.Role</class>
            <class>org.tutiworks.orm.User</class>   
            <properties>            
                <property name="kundera.nodes" value="localhost"/>
                <property name="kundera.port" value="9160"/>
                <property name="kundera.keyspace" value="afrikana"/>
                <property name="kundera.dialect" value="cassandra"/>
                <property name="kundera.ddl.auto.prepare" value="update"/>
                <property name="kundera.client.lookup.class" value="com.impetus.client.cassandra.pelops.PelopsClientFactory" />
                <property name="kundera.cache.provider.class" value="com.impetus.kundera.cache.ehcache.EhCacheProvider"/>
                <property name="kundera.cache.config.resource" value="/ehcache-cassandra.xml"/>                 
            </properties>       
        </persistence-unit>
    </persistence>
```

And the configuration class creating the entityManager looks like:

```
            @Configuration
    public class SpringDataConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{

        @Autowired
        private Environment env;

        @Value("${kundera.nodes}") private String node;
        @Value("${kundera.port}") private String port;
        @Value("${kundera.keyspace}") private String keyspace;
        @Value("${kundera.dialect}") private String dialect;
        @Value("${kundera.ddl.auto.prepare}") private String dbGenerator;
        @Value("${kundera.cache.provider.class}") private String cacheClass;
        @Value("${kundera.client.lookup.class}") private String lookupClass;
        @Value("${kundera.cache.config.resource}") private String configResource;
        @Value("${persistence.unit.name}") private String persistenceUnitName;

        @Bean
        public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
            LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
            em.setPersistenceUnitName(persistenceUnitName);
            return em;
        }

        @Bean
        public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor exceptionTranslation() {
            return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
        }
    }
```

The following class shows how the persistence context is used.

```
        public abstract class GenericDAO< T extends Serializable > {

           private Class<T> clazz;

           @PersistenceContext
           EntityManager entityManager;

           protected void setClazz( Class<T> clazzToSet ){
              this.clazz = clazzToSet;
           }

           public T findOne( String id ){
              return this.entityManager.find( this.clazz, id );
           }

           @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
           public List< T > findAll(){
              return this.entityManager.createQuery( "from " + this.clazz.getName() )
               .getResultList();
           }

           public void save( T entity ){
              this.entityManager.persist( entity );
           }

           public void update( T entity ){
              this.entityManager.merge( entity );
           }

           public void delete( T entity ){
              this.entityManager.remove( entity );
           }
           public void deleteById( String entityId ){
              T entity = this.findOne( entityId );

              this.delete( entity );
           }
        }
```

A sample of the ORM that is mapped to a column family in Apache Cassandra installation looks like the following.

```
      @XmlRootElement(name = "Role")
    @Entity(name="Role")
    @Table(name = "roles", schema = "afrikana@cassandra_pu")
    public class Role implements Serializable {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 9127322651789683331L;

        @Id
        @Column(name="id")
        @XmlID
        private String id;

        @Column(name = "role_name")
        @XmlElement(name = "role_name")
        private String roleName;

        public String getRoleName() {
            return roleName;
        }

        public void setRoleName(String roleName) {
            this.roleName = roleName;
        }

        public String getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(String id) {
            this.id = id;
        }
    }
```

Where would I be going wrong with my configuration? What I'm I missing? How do I fix the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kundera cassandra libraries are running on 1.2.4 version. Ideally 1.2.8 or higher versions should always be backward compatible, but in this case unfortunately they are not!

Comment: When I switch back to v1.2.4, I get the error message: com.impetus.kundera.KunderaException: com.impetus.kundera.KunderaException: Entitymatadata should not be null . According to the configuration I have what could be wrong?

Comment: Looks like, packaging is incorrect and entities are not available on classpath. you may search Kundera github issues. There have been number of discussions around it over there.